# change my main image when a button is clicked

Tags: css

C:\Documents and Settings\Omar.Abulawi\Desktop\t3\main.htm
This is a site i'm working on, now i'm trying to change and replace the main image with different ones according to one of the five menus once they are clicked. But with no use!
Your help and advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please tell us more info...

Comment: If you want change image on mouseover check this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ScDV/

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on what you've said, this JavaScript should do it:

```
function changeimage()
{
    document.getElementById("picture_id").src = "new_file_path";
}
```

Call that function in the `onclick` events of your menus.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this with pure css using The `:target` pseudo class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/YNjek/)**

**Note:** You'll need a modern browser to use this method. (IE9+)

Also, take a look at **[this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/)** which shows some clever ways to simulate click events with css (one of them being the :target pseudo class.

Comment: awesome used CSS very well.. liked it:)